# delphi dbGridEh displays dataset but doesn't allow moving from row to row, doesn't show updates to dataset

Tags: delphi, adodb, dbgrid

I have a `TDataModule` with 2 `TADOQueries` & 2 datasources: Master and Detail.

```
DataModule.DetailQuery.Datasource := MasterQueryDataSource;
```

I display the datasets from these queries in a separate form. A new instance of the form is created each time. The form has a MasterDbGridEh and a DetaildbGridEh bound to the master and the details datasource. When The user is finished with editing, the form is destroyed, the queries are closed. When the user needs to open the window next time, a new instance is created and the queries are activated.

When the form is invoked for the 1st time everythin works just fine.
But the second time I get this issue with the DetailsDbGridEh:
it displays the DataSet with the 1st row selected but I can't move up or down in the grid when I try to scroll. After appending a new row to the dataset the new row is not displayed. 
The dataset AfterScroll event fires when I try to move up or down and the dataset is actually scrolled behind the scenes but the scroll and the changes are not displayed by the dbgrideh.
It seems that after first showing the dataset the dbgrid somehow loses touch to the datasource.

UPDATE 
Structure of queries:
Datamodel consists of entities: ORDER, each order consists of several JOBS, each Job has several Participants.
So there are 3 queries: OrderEditQuery, JobEditQuery and JobParticipantsQuery;
JobEditQuery depends on OrderEditQuery and has parameter ORDER_ID which it takes from ORDEREDITQUERY
JobParticipantsQuery depends on JobEditQuery and has parameter JoB_ID which it takes from JobEditQuery.

When JobEditorForm is opened only one order is edited but the user is supposed to be able to navigate through and edit jobs of the order and through and edit participants of each job

CODE:

code in main form to invoke editor form:

```
with TJobEditorForm.Create(Self, orderID,  // constructor
 jobID, officeID) do
 begin
   ShowModal;
 end;
```

Constructor:

```
constructor TJobEditorForm.Create(AOWner: TComponent; orderID: integer;
  jobID: integer; officeID: integer);
begin
  self.Create(AOwner);
  _orderID := orderID;
  _startingJobID := jobID;
  _officeID := officeID;
end;
```

On form show:

```
procedure TJobEditorForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
   jobEditDataModule.ActivateQueries(_orderID, _officeID); 
   // jobEditdatamodule is the datamodule where the queries sit
end;

procedure TJobEditDataModule.ActivateQueries(orderID, officeID : integer);
begin

  CloseQueries; // put this in to ensure that all queries are closed before they are reopened
  // different auxiliary queries used for look up fields
  Data.VID_ALL.Active := false;
  Data.VID_ALL.Parameters.ParamValues['office'] := officeID;
  Data.VID_ALL.Active := true;

  Data.KOEF_ALL.Active := false;
  Data.KOEF_ALL.Parameters.ParamValues['podr'] := officeID;
  Data.KOEF_ALL.Active := true;

  Data.Jobstatuses_All.Active := true;
  Data.Attract_Channels_All.Active := true;

  JobEditDataModule.Customers.Active := true;
  EmployeeDataModule.Employees.Active := true;

  // this is the query that gives me trouble 
  JobParticipantsQuery.Active := false;

  // main query
  OrderEditQuery.Parameters.ParamValues['orderID'] := orderID;
  OrderEditQuery.Open;
  OrderEditQuery.EnableControls;

  // first details query. Dependent on OrderEditQuery (takes two params: officeID and OrderID.         OrderID is taken from OrderEditQuery, on which JobEditQuery depends)
  JobEditQuery.Active := false;
  JobEditQuery.EnableControls;
  JobEditDataModule.JobEditQuery.Parameters.ParamValues['officeID'] := officeID;
  TDataUtils.EnsureActive( [ JobEditQuery ]);
  JobEditQuery.EnableControls;

  // JobPArticipantsQuery is details query dependent on JobEditQuery.
  JobparticipantsQuery.DisableControls;
  JobparticipantsQuery.EnableControls;
  JobParticipantsQuery.Active := true;
  JobparticipantsQuery.EnableControls;
end;
```

When the editor form is closed, the CloseQueries procedure is executed:

```
procedure TJobEditDataModule.CloseQueries;
 begin
   OrderEditQuery.DisableControls;
   JobParticipantsQuery.DisableControls;
   JobparticipantsQuery.DisableControls;

 JobParticipantsQuery.Close;
 JobEditQuery.Close;
 OrderEditQuery.Close;
end;
```

Comment: The problem is that we can't see your code or screen! :=) Could you add to your q the code you use to create the form, please?

Comment: The difference in behaviour is mostly likely to be to do with how your form is coded.  Try this: if your Form unit defines TmyForm, and there's a variable myForm : TmyForm below the form's declaration in the interface section of the unit, comment the variable out and see if the unit will still compile.  If it won't, add the code where the compiler complains "Undeclared identifier" to your q.

Comment: I removed myForm :TMyForm declaration from the unit, use only instances of TMyForm that I create myself.

Comment: I would start with removing all the disable/enable controls calls, because that seems to be the culprit the second time the form is opened according to what you're describing.
And because everything is done during create/show/close the controls aren't reacting anyway and should not have a huge performance hit

Comment: It would be better to assign the result of creating your JobEditorForm to a variable, rather than using "with TJobEditorForm.Create ...".  You'll find it easier to debug and keep track of what's going on.  In general, you should avoid "with ..." like the plague.  It causes far more trouble with things like debugging than it ever saves in typing.

Comment: Btw, I agree with the comment about removing all the Disabe/EnableControls.  You should only ever use them in pairs, in the same routine, not do one in one place and the other in another, because you'll likely get precisely the problem you describe if they aren't *exactly* balanced.  The reason is that EnableControls doesn't actually do anything until a counter variable descends to zero, so if you have one more Disable than Enable, the controls will remain frozen.  Btw #2, disabling a DataSet's controls just before you close it is pointless, and should be completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for comments and suggestions. After some refactoring I tumbled on the bug: I am disabling controls of JobparticipantsQuery twice in CloseQueries method: JobParticipantsQuery.DisableControls;    JobparticipantsQuery.DisableControls;. After removing second line it started working. Never knew it matters how many times DisableControls is called!